# user_path(user) undefined local variable or method `user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I'm trying to add a Profile page for the users of my App.

I followed railscasts [250](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) & [274](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password) to set up my user authentication & added the below to get a user profile.

**users/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%= @user.name %> Profile</h1>
</div>

<p>
  <b>email:</b>
  <%= @user.email %>
</p>
```

**layouts/_navbar.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "View your Profile", user_path(user) %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

This throws back a `undefined local variable or method 'user'` error.

So I tried adding both of these lines to my **application_controller.rb** :

```
@user = User.all
```

&

```
@user = User.all.find(params[:id])
```

But these returned the following error respectively

```
undefined local variable or method `user'
```

&

```
undefined local variable or method `params'
```

I have `resources :users` in my **routes.rb** file & I've also tried adding `get 'users/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => 'user'` without any success.

Comment: `<%= link_to "View your Profile", user_path(@user) %>` doesn't work for you?

Comment: unless you did something really funky the `params` variable should never be undefined...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go to the show page of the user that is currently logged in:

```
<%= link_to "View your Profile", current_user %>
```

Leave the show action as it was and the routes just with `resources :users`

Comment: Thankyou Zippie, this worked :).  I don't see how current_user can be a route though, seems like magic

Comment: any variable that contains a object from your database can be used to redirect you to the objects show page. The `current_user` is a object of the `User` class so it can be used to redirect you to the user's show page :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your **layouts/_navbar** file. You'll need to define `user`.

Use the helper: `<%= link_to "View your Profile", user_path(current_user) %>`

Or: `<%= link_to "View your Profile", url_for({ :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id => current_person.id }) %>`